# How properly use find_library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have this struct of files:
[image: struct of files]

And i am trying to create executable file, but i have problem in road to this, when i am creating makefile.
I created libsort by cmake like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(sort)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deploy)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/sort.cpp)

set(HEADERS_FILES include/sort.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC include)
```

And by this i created libsort.so in deploy folder.
Now i want to create executable file, so i am trying to run cmake from main folder and i am getting in return:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_library):
  Could not find LIB_FILE using the following names: sort
```

CMakeLists in folder app:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(my_app)

find_library(LIB_FILE sort HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/build/deploy REQUIRED)
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_FILE})
```

I tried with HINTS, without and many possibilities with find_library().
Anyone have idea how to do this properly?

Comment: Why couldn't you copy and paste the text with the file tree as a pre-formatted text here?

Comment: I question if you want to even use find_library() at all in this example instead of add_subdirectory() for me find_library is for finding compiled libraries that are external to my project folder tree. Inside your tree you use add_subdirectory if you are compiling by source.

Comment: add_subdirectory nothing change in this case, same error, so i want, to try step by step do this

Comment: library is in deploy, with .so, I think good result

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_FILE})` would have to change. However @273K gave you an answer that explains the general concept.

Comment: "I tried with HINTS, without and many possibilities with find_library()" - Have you tried to specify in HINTS an absolute path **without any substitutions**? Most likely, you build the `app` project in the `build/` subdirectory, so the hint `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/build/deploy` refers to `build/lib/build/deploy` directory, which doesn't exist at all. (Even if you use a substitution in the hint, you could always print its value with `message()` command and check whether resulted hint is correct.)

Comment: Ye i tried with full hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) usage is incorrect here, it is used for looking for libraries, but not for sources. Use [`add_subdirectory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html):

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(my_app)

add_subdirectory(lib sort)
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} sort)
```

Comment: It's correct, but it is not possibility to use find_library()? And can you say me how work sort int add_subdirectory?

Comment: `find_library` is for a built library. If you want to build it independently, then try `find_library(LIB_FILE sort HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/build/deploy REQUIRED)`. You used improper `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, that is `app/build` that does not have `lib/build/deploy`.

Comment: Man, I am really grateful to you. I was trying many times, thx for both ways. Once again thanks for help. If you have one moment, pls tell me why in way with add_subdirectory you gave to add_subdirectory sort like on of elements. I understand that this is name or something like this. But i would be really happy if you say more few words how it works. Thanks again

Comment: any particular reason you're passing `sort` as the (optional) `binary_dir` parameter of `add_subdirectory` here?

Comment: For placing `sort`'s generated and build files in the convenient location `app/build/sort`.